# Restringir duplicados de una columna hasta cierto valor mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla sencilla con algunos valores duplicados, necesito restrigir los duplicados a un maximo de 3 duplicados por columna. Algo así como tener una columna UNIQUE pero el triple. Creo que no podría encontrar algo tan primitivo como el UNIQUE pero preferirió no necesitar algo mas elaborado.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Ejemplo, tenemos esta tablita con esos values

```
create table DemoTable1389(StudentId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, StudentMarks int);

insert into DemoTable1389(StudentMarks) values(97);
insert into DemoTable1389(StudentMarks) values(97);
insert into DemoTable1389(StudentMarks) values(97);


+-----------+-------------+
| StudentId | StudentMarks|
+-----------+-------------+
| 1         | 97          |
| 2         | 97          |
| 3         | 97          |
+-----------+-------------+
```

entonces con la configuracion que busco me lo prohibiría si intentará hacer:

```
insert into DemoTable1389(StudentMarks) values(97);
```

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de lo q quieres hacer y pon la estructura de tu tabla y aclara el campo por el que quieres agrupar

Comment: podrías crear un procedimiento almacenado que revise cuantos duplicados hay de cierto registro en base a x datos que definas necesarios para saber si es duplicado. Si el resultado de esa consulta es mayor o igual que 3, inserta. si no no hace nada

Comment: @L.Ronquillo El problema sería que si por diversas conecciones se usa el procedimiento simultaneamente, se podría evadir el limite, no?

Comment: @novatilloesevato existe la posibilidad de, pero ese riesgo siempre va a existir sin importar lo que hagas, a no ser que hicieras una "lista de espera" en otra tabla o algo similar, pero extiende demasiado tu pregunta.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo Ok, pensé que existiría una solución tan comoda como el UNIQUE pero sino esperaba algo ya creado por mysql entonces como parece no haber una solución de ese tipo solamente crearé el procedimiento. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from tabla
where campo = valor
```

Esta consulta te cuenta la cantidad de registros repetidos dado la condición que deseas, si la consulta devuelve un número >= 3, pues no insertas, caso contrario insertas.

Comment: El problema sería que si por diversas conecciones uso el count() simultaneamente antes de alcanzar el limite estas pensarían que el limite no se ha alcanzado y superarían el limite, no?

Comment: No creo que eso suceda,  el count contaría igual, ej si hay dos usuarios insertando datos concurrentemente, nunca los dos insertaran al mismo tiempo, las probabilidades de que eso ocurra son mínimas por no decir nulas

Comment: No te compliques tanto, los sistemas de base de datos de los aeropuertos tienen una concurrencia altísima y millones de transacciones en un segundo, las bases de datos están hechas para lidiar con esas colisiones y liberarnos a nosotros de esos problemas